# How to achieve a new bar in each run for sonarqube code coverage?

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab

I am facing a problem. Presently working on Sonar integration in Gitlab. 
The goal is that on consecutive runs of the pipeline, code coverage has to be at least equal to the previous run. So if the last run had code coverage of 75%, the pipeline will not succeed until the coverage is at least 75%. If I now have code coverage at 76%, then that is the new bar. Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can have a look to `Quality Gates` where you can define Boolean conditions based on measure thresholds against which projects are measured

Comment: @Ros5292: Thank you for your response! The one I mentioned above is dynamic i.e. it keeps on changing with each new build. Do you think I can achieve it using quality gates? There we just put a number to be achieved at every build.

Comment: @Ros5292: Also please check my new question that I have added. Thank you!!  Link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557015/api-requests-format-in-gitlab"